# Require modification in columnsMenuTab ag grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Require information to modify the columnMenuTab in ag grid.
Also require the events or callback information when checkbox checked in  ag grid columnMenuTab.

Currently using 
Angular 6
ag-grid V 19.0

Comment: Please explain your problem with proper description and some code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for response refere - https://plnkr.co/edit/A4wWuH8HIuPAXhxaKCqP?p=preview. For Athlete columnMenuTab require to disable the Athlete checkbox and require the events or callback when we click on any checkbox of columnMenuTab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use set this property to true in your athlete column def

```
  {
    headerName: "Athlete",
    field: "athlete",
    width: 150,
    lockVisible: true,
  }
```

As per [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#columns), `columnVisible` event is triggered when column's visibility is toggled.

> columnVisible -   A column, or group of columns, was hidden / shown.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance will check that.